# Crashlytics not receiving crashes from TestFlight

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, fastlane

I've installed Crashlytics to my App and receive crash reports for when I crash using the simulator. However crashes that happen through releases on TestFlight do not appear.

I installed Crashlytics directly since I don't use CococaPods. I used the following guide https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install.

I made sure that I've set `DWARF with dSYM File` as the Debug Information Format.

[image]

Bit stuck as to where the problem is. Could it be related to the fact that TestFlight targets Release instead of Debug?

I use fastlane for releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a upload-dSYM phase in you Fastfile? If not - it can be reason.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. Fastlane wasn't uploading the dSYM and it was missing on the Crashlytics dashboard. I've uploaded the missing ones and the crashes are coming through now.